# Printing to screen

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that solves a maze. i have no errors in the program. but when run the program, the maze doesn't show up. i just get:

```
assignment4b.Maze@2a46b75b
Your move (1:north, 2:west, 3:east, 4:south, 5:help):
```

This is how the file im reading from looks like:

```
  20 7  Number of columns and rows 
    0 18  Exit square (rows and columns start at 0)
    6 12  Entrance square 
    XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX X 
    X            XXXX  X 
    X XXXXX XXXXX   XX X 
    X XXXXX XXXXXXX XX X 
    X            XX XX X
    X XXXXXXXXXX XX    X 
    XXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXX
```

This is how my  main looks like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Question5 
    {
        public static void main (String[]args)
        {
            // Construct the maze
            Maze m = new Maze("Maze.txt");
            System.out.println(m);

            while (!m.isOut())
            {
                    // input from the keyboard
                    int move;
                    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.print("Your move (1:north, 2:west, 3:east, 4:south, 5:help): ");
                    move = kb.nextInt();

                    System.out.println();

                    // Process the player's selection
                    switch (move)
                    {
                    case '1':
                        m.goNorth();
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        m.goWest();
                        break;
                    case '3':
                        m.goEast();
                        break;
                    case '4':
                        m.goSouth();
                        break;
                    case '5':
                        m.showPath(System.out);
                        System.out.println();
                        break;
                    }


                    // Display the new maze (unless help was selected)
                    if (move != 5)
                    {
                        System.out.print(m);
                        System.out.print("\n");
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is how my Maze Class looks like:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Maze implements MazeInterface
{

        public static final int CLEAR = 0;
        public static final int WALL = 1;
        public static final int VISITED = 2;
        public static final int PATH = 3;

        private int row;
        private int col;
        // 2D array to represent the maze (on the heap)
        private int[][] maze;

        // entrance and exit points of the maze
        private Location entrance = new Location();
        private Location exit = new Location();

        // Location of the creature
        private Location creature = new Location();

        public Maze(String filename) throws IOException
        {

            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            Scanner readFile = new Scanner (fis);


               if( readFile != null)
               {
                   row = readFile.nextInt();
                   col= readFile.nextInt();      
               }

                // Maze structure
                // Create the maze on the heap: 2D array of row*col ints
                maze = new int[row][col];
                for(int i=0; i<row; ++i)
                {
                    for(int x = 0; x<col;x++)
                    {
                        row = i;
                        col = x;
                    }
                }

                // Read the maze line by line
                String mazeLine;
                for(int r=0; r<row; ++r)
                {
                    // eof must not have been reached

                    while(readFile.hasNextLine())
                    {
                        mazeLine=readFile.toString();

                        for(int c=0; c<col; ++c)
                        {
                            // mazeline must be made of 'X' and ' ' only
                            if(mazeLine.charAt(c) ==' ' || mazeLine.charAt(c) =='X');
                            {
                                maze[r][c] = ((mazeLine.charAt(c) ==' ')?CLEAR:WALL);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                // The entrance and exit must not be blocked
                if(maze[entrance.r][entrance.c]!=WALL &&  maze[exit.r][exit.c]!=WALL)
                {
                    // The creature is at the entrance
                    creature = entrance;
                }   

        }

        public boolean goNorth()
        {
            // Location north of the creature
            Location north = creature;
            north.r--;
            // if north is inside of the maze and the square
            // at north is not a wall, we can move the creature
            if (insideMaze(north) && square(north) != WALL)
            {
                creature = north;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public boolean goSouth()
        {
            // Location south of the creature
            Location south = creature;
            south.r++;
            // if south is inside of the maze and the square
            // at south is not a wall, we can move the creature
            if (insideMaze(south) && square(south) != WALL)
            {
                creature = south;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public boolean goWest()
        {
            // Location west of the creature
            Location west = creature;
            west.c--;
            // if west is inside of the maze and the square
            // at west is not a wall, we can move the creature
            if (insideMaze(west) && square(west) != WALL)
            {
                creature = west;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public boolean goEast()
        {
            // Location east of the creature
            Location east = creature;
            east.c++;
            // if east is inside of the maze and the square
            // at east is not a wall, we can move the creature
            if (insideMaze(east) && square(east) != WALL)
            {
                creature = east;
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public boolean isOut()
        {
            return (creature == exit);
        }

        public void showPath(OutputStream out)
        {
            // =there is a path
            boolean success = false;

            // Look for the path recursively
            findPath(creature,success);

            // print the path (if we found one0
            if (success)
            {
                System.out.println(this);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println( "There is no solution path");
            }

            // Remove the VISITED and PATH marks
            // (set such squares to CLEAR)
            for (int i = 0; i < row; ++i)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < col; ++j)
                {
                    if (maze[i][j] == PATH || maze[i][j] == VISITED)
                    {
                            maze[i][j] = CLEAR;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public <ostream> ostream leftShift(ostream out, Maze m) 
        {
            // X: wall
            // C: creature
            //  : empty square
            // .: path leading to the exit

            // character on the square
            char l;
            for (int r = 0; r < m.row; ++r)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c < m.col; ++c)
                {
                    switch (m.maze[r][c])
                    {
                    case CLEAR:
                    case VISITED:
                        l = ' ';
                        break;
                    case WALL:
                        l = 'X';
                        break;
                    case PATH:
                        l = '.';
                        break;
                    }
                    // Check for the creature
                    if (r == m.creature.r && c == m.creature.c)
                    {
                        l = 'C';
                        System.out.println(l);
                    }

                }

            }
            return out;
        }




        public void markSquareAsVisited(Location l)
        {

                maze[l.r][l.c] = VISITED;
        }

        public void markSquareAsPath(Location l)
        {

                maze[l.r][l.c] = PATH;

        }

        public int square(Location l)
        {

                return maze[l.r][l.c];
        }

        public boolean insideMaze(Location l)
        {
            return (l.c >= 0 && l.c < col && l.r >= 0 && l.r < row);
        }

        public void findPath(Location l, Boolean success)
        {
            // This square is being visited
            // Mark it as such
            markSquareAsVisited(l);

            // If it is the exit square, we are done
            // Mark the square as part of the path
            // set success to true
            if (l == exit)
            {
                success = true;
                markSquareAsPath(l);
                return;
            }

            // try all possible moves from this square
            // north, south, east and west
            Location north = l;
            north.r--;
            Location south = l;
            south.r++;
            Location east = l;
            east.c++;
            Location west = l;
            west.c--;

            // If we haven't found the winning path yet and we can go north
            // and we haven't been there already, look for the winning path
            // starting from north
            if (!success && insideMaze(north) && square(north) != WALL && square(north) != VISITED)
            {
                findPath(north,success);
            }
            // If we haven't found the winning path yet and we can go south
            // and we haven't been there already, look for the winning path
            // starting from south
            if (!success && insideMaze(south) && square(south) != WALL && square(south) != VISITED)
            {
                findPath(south,success);
            }
            // If we haven't found the winning path yet and we can go east
            // and we haven't been there already, look for the winning path
            // starting from east
            if (!success && insideMaze(east) && square(east) != WALL && square(east) != VISITED)
            {
                findPath(east,success);
            }
            // If we haven't found the winning path yet and we can go west
            // and we haven't been there already, look for the winning path
            // starting from west
            if (!success && insideMaze(west) && square(west) != WALL && square(west) != VISITED)
            {
                findPath(west,success);
            }

            // If success is true, this location is part of a 
            // solution path. Mark the square as part of the path.
            if (success)
            {
                markSquareAsPath(l);
            }
        }




}
```

And this is how my Location Class looks like:

```
public class Location implements LocationInterface
{
    // store a location in the maze
    // r and c are the row and column of the location in the maze
        public int r;
        public int c;

        // Comparison of 2 locations
        public boolean equalsTo(Location l)
        {
            return (r == l.r && c == l.c);
        }

        public boolean notEqualsTo(Location l)
        {
            return (r != l.r || c != l.c);
        }

}
```

Comment: I really dont see why i was downgraded

Answer (score 2):

This is causing the output:

```
        Maze m = new Maze("Maze.txt");
        System.out.println(m);
```

If you want to print something else, you need to implement the `toString()` method on the `Maze` class.  For example, if you implemented it like this:

```
public String toString() {
    return "I'm a maze";
}
```

Instead of saying

```
assignment4b.Maze@2a46b75b
Your move (1:north, 2:west, 3:east, 4:south, 5:help):
```

It will say

```
I'm a maze
Your move (1:north, 2:west, 3:east, 4:south, 5:help):
```

Answer (score 0):

You're printing out the reference to the object. Since your maze is a multi-line object, you'd be better off writing a `print()` method on `Maze`, or you can override `toString()` to provide a more helpful string representation.